# Build Eclipse never ended

Tags: eclipse, build

I installed the latest version of eclipse: 4.3.0
I also installed Android
Since the beginning of my Android project when I run a Build, often I have to kill Eclipse because it never stops.
I can not find much on the web, that's why I ask for your help.

Thank you very much in advance to those who give a helping hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my answer:

First add at the first line of your **eclipse.ini** file (in your Eclipse installation) the    **-clean**      option.
Then, **most importantly, I did not added the Home directory on my Windows** so:

In Windows 7, type "environment" at the start menu

- Select "Edit environment variables for your account"
- Click the "New" button.
- Enter "HOME" in the name field
- Enter "%USERPROFILE%" or some other path in the value field.
  Click OK, and OK again.

**And finaly, use instructions refered in this [LINK](http://blog.pdark.de/2011/09/02/restoring-a-corrupted-workspace-in-eclipse/)**

**If its steel not working, go and trie this topic : [LINK](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html)**

I hope this can help someone else!

See you soon and good luck!